# How to downgrade yarn tag version of a repository using a dependency?

Tags: git, github, yarnpkg

I screwed up at work and patched instead of tagging a commit as a major release on an addon.. so now I am trying to get rid of that old tag, and revert the repositories that use that addon, to the previous version.

I tried deleting the wrong tag on github itself, as well as using
`git tag -d [version]` and `git push origin :refs/tags/[version]`. Checked github as well as git tag to ensure that the wrong tag is gone from my addon.

I tried to remove the old yarn.lock of the repositories that use that addon, and do a yarn install again, but it keeps using the non-existent tag. Tried `yarn cache clean` too but it still doesn't work